# How To Make data trigger update only one item

Tags: wpf, binding, datatrigger

I am trying to highlight an item in the list view on a particular condition.I have Made Highlight property in the code behind which is making the decision and it is bind to a datatrigger.
The problem is that When one item in the list is changed, data trigger is updating all the item in the list view

Data trigger in the xaml

```
<DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding ElememtName=UserControl, Path=Highlighted}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Property in the code behind

```
public bool Highlighted
{
    get
    {
        return this.highlighted;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.highlighted)
        {
            this.highlighted = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("Highlighted");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You've not shown us enough markup to know how you do the listview items. I would expose a highlighted property from whatever viewmodel I used per row. Probably apply the datatrigger on itemcontainerstyle.

Comment: I have created datatrigger in a style of target type ListViewItem and the same style is used in listview "ItemContainerStyle" property

Comment: You bind all items to the one and only `Highlighted` property, aren't you? So of course they will all be highlighted.